How can I see requests/responses using Chrome F12
I am trying to debug an issue that occurs on only 1 customers system (a Chromebook). It is acting like a single click on the button sends the request 4 times. And the app server is on Azure.
If this occurs on my system I would fire up Fiddler and look at the request/responses. Is there a way to do this with Chrome F12? The network tab, from my looking at it, shows the files the browser requests. But it does not show other request/responses.
I need to see if the request from clicking the button is sent over the wire 1 time (problem is on the server) or 4 times (problem is on the client).

simply open DevTools (F12) and navigate to Network.
With the start recording button (left hand side) 1 u can start recording the messages.
